# react-router IndexRoute is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

I created the code below

```
<Route path="admin" component={App} >
  <IndexRoute component={Product_Category} />
  <Route path="product">
    <Route path="category" component={Product_Category} />
    <Route path="register" component={Product_Register} />
    <Route path="manage" component={Product_Mgt} />
    <Route path="brand" component={Product_Brand} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="library">
    <Route path="promotion" component={Library_Promotion} />
    <Route path="best" component={Library_Best} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

and I changed the code like below

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="admin" component={BasicSet}>
    <IndexRoute component={Product_Category} />
    <Route path="product">
      <Route path="category" component={Product_Category} />
      <Route path="register" component={Product_Register} />
      <Route path="manage" component={Product_Mgt} />
      <Route path="brand" component={Product_Brand} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="library">
      <Route path="promotion" component={Library_Promotion} />
      <Route path="best" component={Library_Best} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

After I changed the code, only `<Route path="admin" component={BasicSet}` works. Except for that, none of pages are shown. In console, there is no error. When I remove `<Route path="admin" component={BasicSet}`, all of pages are shown. I don't know why. Please solve this problem.

Also, code below is working.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Product_Category} />
  <Route path="product">
    <Route path="category" component={Product_Category} />
    <Route path="register" component={Product_Register} />
    <Route path="manage" component={Product_Mgt} />
    <Route path="brand" component={Product_Brand} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="library">
    <Route path="promotion" component={Library_Promotion} />
    <Route path="best" component={Library_Best} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

BasicSet.jsx code return only other components that works.

```
class BasicSet extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <Nav />
            <Menu />
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: use react-router-dom instead of react-router.. it will solve all of your issues..

Comment: can you share the code for your BasicSet component

Comment: I think you are missing a closing `/` for `<Route path="admin" component={BasicSet}>`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri had that been the case there would have been a compilation error in jsx.

Comment: @nyeonkim in your BasicSet render method you are not returning {this.props.children}, that is the reason all the nested routes are not recognised.


 Hope this helps.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh You case will be valid if the OP is trying to render other routes as children of BasicSet

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it is trying to render it as a children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out,

```
class BasicSet extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <Nav />
             {this.props.children}
            <Menu />
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```